# Multiline + pipeline command assigns values to variables in bash

Tags: bash

I have writen a bash file like this:

```
  JSESSIONID=$(curl -I 'http://17....212' \
  -H 'Accept: text/h...b3;q=0.7' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: zh...8' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: ma...0' \
  -H 'Connection: k...ve' \
  -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/118.0.0.0 Safari/537.36' \
  --insecure|grep -o -e "JSESSIONID=\(.*\); P"|sed "s/JSESSIONID=//g"|sed "s/; P//g")
  echo $(JSESSIONID)
```

(Apostrophe is for privacy)

I want to get JSESSIONID, I can run it in the command-line, and it will return a pure string: The JSESSIONID. However, I dont know how to assign it to a variable. By using the code above, it will shows:

`/etc/rc.common: line 37: JSESSIONID: not found`

I know this question is very basic, but I have searched for a long time and have not found a workable answer.

have tried to switch "$()" to "``", But it is useless.

Comment: You are trying to run a command named `JSESSIONID`, capture its output, and then print that.  None of which has anything to do with your variable named `JSESSIONID`.  You are looking for `echo ${JSESSIONID}`, instead.

Comment: `$(foo)` runs a command named `foo`. This is unrelated to the possible existence of a variable named `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSESSIONID already contain result of execution your command. You don't need to run it again with [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution).

For getting value use

```
echo "${JSESSIONID}"
```

or

```
echo "$JSESSIONID"
```